# Bracha on Hallal Chol HaMoed Pesach (in regards to Sephardim)

Tags: minhag, blessing, passover, chol-hamoed, hallel

I know that according to the psak of the Shulchan Aruch the Sephardim (among others -- The Gra, many Kehillas in Yerushalayim including Chassidei Karlin, Chassidei Biyan I think, and Chassidei Chabad (in some cases when there is no shliach tzibbur making the bracha which I believe is their minhag)) don't make a bracha on Hallel (chetzi Hallel) that is said on Rosh Chodesh. While I don't have a specific reason to think otherwise, is the same true for the Hallel that is said on Chol HaMoed Pesach?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%98%D7%95

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for Pesach Chol HaMoed, Sephardim recite the abridged version of Hallel and without any blessings. (cf. Yalkut Yosef 488:18)

Comment: And the last day of yom tov as well